# Webforms Response.Redirect() different behaviour for route and page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, webforms

- Webforms ASP.NET 4.61

I have the following route configuration in place:

```
aRoutes.MapPageRoute("routePageA", "page/a", "~/Pages/A.aspx");
aRoutes.MapPageRoute("routePageB", "page/b", "~/Pages/B.aspx");
```

I have code in a click handler for A.aspx that is redirecting to B.aspx however I get different behaviour as follows:

1. When redirecting to the route without ending request:

   Response.Redirect("/page/b");

the events fired are:

- A.aspx Page_Load()    <-- Why? I am already in PostBack.
- B.aspx Page_Load()

  2. When redirecting to the route without ending request:

  Response.Redirect("/page/b, true");

the events fired are:

- A.aspx Page_Load()       <-- Why? I am already in PostBack.
- B.aspx Page_Load()

  3. When redirecting to aspx directly:

  Response.Redirect("/Pages/B.aspx");

the events fired are:

- B.aspx Page_Load()

The behaviour I am expecting is 3. But why does this only behave this way when the ASPX is the redirection target. Can someone explain to me why directing to a route produces different behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectToRoute instead of Response.Redirect(). Try this instead.

```
return RedirectToRoute("routePageB");
```

Comment: I guess you meant Response.RedirectToRoute("SomeRouteName"); Makes no difference. Also as I am in a OnClick there is no return value as the method is void.

Comment: It should work fine but I am just thinking why it is behaving weird in your case.